# insert a Python list into a column in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have list and I want to enter each element of that list into associated indexed cells of a column in MYSQL using Python.

E.g

```
lst = [11,22,33,44,55,66]
```

MYSql column:

```
Data
11
22
33
44
55
66.
```

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

Following code will do the work:

```
values = [list([item]) for item in lst]
cursor.executemany(u'INSERT INTO `tbl`(`Data`)(%s)', values)
```