# TypeError: ' Float object not Iterable' in my sql query script

Tags: python, typeerror

I know this question has been asked but I can't find the answer to my issue

I have a list of data type `float`  called `fiveMin`

```
[10.0, 13.0, ....... 34.0, 22.0]
```

about 72 elements in all

I want to load them in to a column in a mysql table

```
for item in fiveMin:
    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO abc (five) VALUES (?,?,?)', item)
```

my connection works but when the script executes the query I get

`TypeError: 'Float object not Iterable'`

Comment: Just review the docs. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html  - this expects an iterable not an individual value. The placeholder is also not `?`

Comment: An answer to loading list values to columns is answered @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225128/insert-a-python-list-into-a-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is likely because [`executemany()` expects an iterable argument](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) at the end and not a discrete element. Try with:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO abc (five) VALUES (%f,%f,%f)',
                   [(item, item, item) for item in fiveMin])
```

and you'll insert each item three times (makes little sense, but the best I can tell you without context)

if you want to insert only a single value the call would be using `(item,)` as parameter, so you build a tuple from a discrete element.

---

edit: I updated my answer to show up the correct usage of the `executemany` method. Here, I use a list comprehension to create the argument your insert statement expects and I updated the insert statement so it takes a float format parameter.

Comment: kuddos to @pvg for making me not have to google the manual page 

Comment: thanks for the answer i will try it out, to give context i am pulling specific useful data of something happening in a time window, from a large data warehouse.To make it presentable to my end user I am adding the data to a database I own. So i run a a function to pull the data for 72 elements and dump in to a list, i then want to use that list as input in to my sql query (i am a noob as well so doesn't help)

Comment: Is the list comprehension necessary? A generator expression would work too, right? --- `((item, item, item) for item in fiveMin)`

Comment: I wouldn't expect much from using a generator, as anyway to build the query the generator would need to end before passing the value as argument to `cursor.executemany()`, so if a generator works it would'nt change much in terms of performance… And usually to build a query you won't be working on huge numbers, so the added value of a generator vs iterator would be marginal at best.